# what should i do now to solve the issue because it is showing x is not defined?

Tags: python, function

```
def fun2(x):
    return 2*x
a = fun2(x)
print(a)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ea6b97e2013c> in <module>
      1 def fun2(x):
      2     return 2*x
----> 3 a = fun2(x)
      4 print(a)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: What is x equal to? Try putting `x = 3` (or some other number) before you call `a = fun2(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass a value to x. That‘s why.

When you call your function, you need to pass a value to it, for instance: 5.

`a = fun2(5)`

Answer (score 0):

You have passed function parameter as x in 3rd line. Either set x before passing argument or You should pass a number in third line like :
a=fun2(4)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a value to x by asking the user to enter a number, which will be assigned to variable x. `float` converts the input number from a string to a floating point number.

```py
x = float(input("Enter a number: ")) # Enter a value for x.
def fun2(x):
    return 2*x
a = fun2(x)
print(a)
```